# How to set a directory and run a file on C++?

Tags: c++, macos

As far as I know, using `system()` on the program is like typing on the terminal, and if I put on the terminal `cd Desktop` it sets the directory to the desktop as it should.

So I am trying to set a directory like `system(cd ~/Desktop);` or `system(cd Desktop);`, so then execute a file typing `./theFileName`, but it isn't working. And if after that I put `system(ls);` it shows the files of the directory that this program itself is.

PD: I am on mac

Comment: You can''t do it using more than 1 system() call. Each call of system() is independent.

Comment: You need to change the current working directory for your program - that may (possibly will, depending on the host system) be inherited by child processes subsequently created using `system()`.   Catch is, the techniques vary between implementations (host and compiler).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`system` spawns a new shell session every time you run it, so your cwd isn't maintained between functions. You can either provide the full path like `~/Desktop/theFileName`, or use a semicolon like `cd ~/Desktop; ./theFileName`.

Comment: Hello, using `cd ~/Desktop; ./theFileName` says `sh: ./test_file.txt: Permission denied` What do I do?

Comment: Your file isn't executable. If you want to forcefully execute it then you can run `chmod +x test_file.txt`.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The command you provide in `system()` is executed by a new shell
that is launched at this occasion.
The `cd` command is executed by this shell but that doesn't change
anything for your process that lauched the shell.

In order to actually change the current directory for your process,
you need the `chdir()` system call.
( https://linux.die.net/man/2/chdir )